# Creating a profle page dynamically that grabs data from my local JSON folder

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native

I am a RN newbiw and I am building a little project for myself as part of my learning process. I was able to populate a list of names in my directory screen, dynamically, from a JSON file I created locally in RN. However, now I am trying to get each button from that list of names to take me to that particular character's profile with their basic info. When I click on it, nothing happens. I am really not sure what is going on. However, I was thinking: if I were to create another folder so that I display a profile, when that button is clicked on in the directory, how would I go about that?  Any help or leads is appreciated!

This is how I have my JSON file set up:

```
//characters.js    
const characters = [
      { id: "1", name: "Homer Simpson", occupation: "Nuclear Safety Inspector"},
      { id: "2", name: "Marge Simpson", occupation: "Stay-at-home mom"},
      { id: "3", name: "Bart Simpson", occupation: "Student" },
      { id: "4", name: "Lisa Simpson", occupation: "Student" },
      { id: "5", name: "Maggie Simpson", occupation: "Baby" },
      { id: "6", name: "Scratchy", occupation: "Cat" }
    ];
    export default characters;
```

This is my character directory, where I was able to pull in the list of characters dynamically.

```
//CharacterDirectory.js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Button, FlatList } from "react-native";
import { withNavigation } from "react-navigation";
import {
    createStackNavigator,
    createAppContainer,
    createBottomTabNavigator
  } from "react-navigation";
import characters from "../Data/Characters";

class CharacterDirectory extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: "The Simpsons",
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#53b4e6"
        },
        headerTintColor: "#f6c945",
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: "bold"
        },
      };
  render() {
      const { navigation } = this.props;
      const type = navigation.getParam('type');
      const typeData = characters[type];
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {characters.map( (data,index) => (
                <Button 
                    title={`${data.name}`}
                    onPress={() => 
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('characters', {
                            type : type,
                            item: data
                        })}
                        />
            ))}
        </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignContent: "center"
    }
  });
  export default withNavigation(CharacterDirectory);
```

The tricky part for me has been, what I need to pass as an argument in the onPress function since 'characters' is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please show your navigator definition.

what you need to pass to the navigate function is instead of 'characters' what you defined in your navigator.

Let's say you have AppNavigator like this

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);
```

Then you have 2 routes available, 'Home' and 'Details',
Then you could call navigate('Home') or navigate('Details')

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Thank you, I tried it, and when I put a route in, all the buttons in the directory take me to that specific screen, which is what I want for a particular button, but not for all of them. Any ideas on what I should do?

Comment: @csb00 yeah, you need to pass parameters to your route like you're doing already, then retrieve them with `navigation.getParam('itemId', 'NO-ID');`, check the documentation for more information https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html